# UIButton System button and image not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, system

I am using storyboard, and inside the main view I have 2 elements, a view on the top that is 44px in height, then a WKWebview below it.

I'm trying to add a home button in this top view.  I added a 'system' button, selected house.fill as the image and set the content to left alignment, vertical center, but it does not show.

I then added a regular image object, then selected house.fill as it's image, set Content Mode to Aspect Fill.  It didn't show up either.

I then added a label, put some text in it, and it does show.

As a test, I set the background color of the button and image controls to blue and purple respectively.  This is what it looks like in the designer and a screen shot of what is showing in the app.

Why is the house image not showing correctly?

[image: How it looks in the designer]

[image: Screenshot from device]

Comment: *** Update, this works as expected on 13.2 on an XR.  The screenshot above is on an iPhone 6 on 12.4.2.  My project target is iOS 11.

Comment: I think I've answered my own question.  The house.fill is a SF font which is only on iOS13.

Comment: Thank you. I had the same issue and results now it is okay as well.